# How to chmod for specific folder and all its folders upward

Tags: unix, chmod

I'm new to unix,currently working in a SAS environment where Unix is a must.

I have a question regarding chmod to a specific folder. I have this directory: `/user/monthly/december/`

Under this are `data` and `input` folders:

- `/user/monthly/december/data`
- `/user/monthly/december/input`

under `data` folder is `format` folder. And I want to chmod this (`/user/monthly/december/data/format`) to `chmod 777`

but I can't do that since I need to first chmod `/user/monthly/december/data`

I usually do `chmod -R` but I don't want to change the permission of `input` folder. I only want to change the permissions of all the folders you can see in this path: `/user/monthly/december/data/format`

Is there a way to specify this `chmod`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could split the path to your desired directory and built it back up.

```
path=/user/monthly/december/data
for x in $(echo $path | tr -s '/' '\n'); do 
       z=$z"/"$x
       chmod -v 770 $z
done
```